# Finding user information in different databases and tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lot of different databases and tables that contain user information. I would like to write a query, that would find all the necessary information. So when I use "where" clause (e.g. where Email = 'Example@example.com', or where Name = 'Mister Holmes' etc), it should bring up the results I'm looking for and search from all the related databases and tables.

My idea is to make a new view, bring all the related tables in there, and then join the necessary columns somehow. Is that possible?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Check this, I hope this will help.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: The problem isn't the "where" clause actually. Rather how to select all these databases and tables (how to join them in "from" clause I suppose).

Comment: You just do a "WHERE {Value} APPEARS IN ANY OBJECT". A Query works against a defined set of objects, where you know their design. You need to know what table and column your data will be in. If you have related tables ,you need to join those, not the RDBMS. If you don't know, you need to learn your database.

Comment: There is no "easy" solution because you're misinterpreting how SQL works; it up to you to tell the RDBMS exactly what you're looking for, not give it a vague request and it works out your intention.

Comment: Yes i do know the database names as well as the table names. I can of course search them one by one, but that would take a huge amount of time. I would need a query that would search all the tables from those databases at once. All the databases are in the same server as well.

Comment: So if you know the table and columns that the value will appear in, why do you need to search every table and every column? If you know, you don't need to do that. It's like knowing where your car is in the car park, but still checking every single parking space; there's no need. Just check the column in the correct table.

Comment: I know the databases, tables and columns, yes. But I don't know where the value, that I'm searching, is appearing. I mean, I have to write a query/script that could easily check all those tables/columns if any user information is present.
Like i said, there are many databases and tables to check from.

Comment: There is no easy query; that's my point. You need to know your design, and where a value (say an email address) would be. Again there is no `SELECT * FROM {All Databases}.{All Tables} WHERE {Any Column} = 'abc@def.com';` You need to be specific about the columns, table, schemas, and databases you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just describe my way - Because I have many different databases with different storaged infos about users, I collect all of them with INSERT and every time I am looking for WHERE SOMETHING, I am running this:

- truncate target table (which is already prepared with necessary colls like NAME, LOGIN, RIGHTS, APPS, NOTES, ...)
- filling target table with data from VIEWs, which are specific for each db / apps / or user groups

This two points I stored in procedure. Maybe it is not quickest way, but searching and filtering above one static table is much more safe and less consuming then searching in twenty views.
But, be aware, I you are not alone DBA and you have collegues which are playing the role of administrating sql in your area, I think, this solution is not lucky.

Or do you have standard user informations in server_principals, server_role_members, database_principals, database_permissions, schemas, ... ?